# How to set different font sizes depending on the screen size in Angular Material?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Im trying to optimize my Angular Material landingpage for mobile devices.

Is there a way to have different font sizes for the headline depending on the screen size without writing custom css?

In this example h1 with md-display-3 would be too large on mobile devices:

```
<h1 class="center white md-display-3">This is a headline</h1>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a quick lookup I saw that it is indeed possible.
[Angular Material documentation : Typography](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/CSS/typography)
Simply replace `.md-display-3` to `md-display-2`.

Comment: Ok, so how would you change the class depending on the screen size?

Comment: Maybe try to use these directives on the [Material Documentation on layout options](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options) 
Make two lines, only one would display :
    <h1 **show-gt-sm** class="center white md-display-3">This is a headline on greater than small screens (gt 960px)</h1>
    <h2 **hide show-gt-sm** class="center white md-display-2">This is a headline on smaller screens (lt 960px)</h2>

Couldn't test it though.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick for me:  `<h1 class="center white md-display-4" hide show-gt-sm>This is a headline on greater than small screens (gt 960px)</h1>  <h2 class="center white md-display-2" hide-gt-sm>This is a headline on smaller screens (lt 960px)</h2>`

Answer (score 1):

To adjust your font size according to your browser, add this meta tag to your document.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class based on the flex size you are displaying, which determines number of columns, etc... When you use the [Angular Material Containers](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container) sizes, the different sections can each then have different fonts.

However, you might be better to not change the font size, but instead use the flexbox layout, and show your text at a consistant size, but have your layout flow to fit better on different devices.

```
<div layout="column" class="zero">
  <div flex="33" flex-md="{{ vm.box1Width }}" class="one"></div>
  <div flex="33" layout="{{ vm.direction }}" layout-md="row" class="two">
    <div flex="22" flex-md="10" hide-lg class="two_one"></div>
    <div flex="30px" show hide-md="{{ vm.hideBox }}" flex-md="25" class="two_two"></div>
    <div flex="20" flex-md="65" class="two_three"></div>
  </div>
  <div flex class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Or, you can change displays and use the Angular to show or hide sections based on screen size.  See [Show and Hide](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options).

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using pure CSS. You can use vh (viewport Height) & vw (viewport width) as the font size attribute. It will be full responsive to all screen sizes. 
10vh : 10% of viewport height (i.e., For mobile it will render small, For Desktop It will render larger)

Comment: This is a pretty clever approach if you combine it with media queries, so that  you don't end up with gigantic fonts on larger screens :-)